# Choice of vectors from basis in Gram-Schmidt process

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, gram-schmidt

Say I have a basis for $\mathbb{c}^{2}$ composed of the vectors $(1,1), (4i,2i )$ with complex inner product. When I construct my orthogonal basis using the Gram-Schmidt process how do I make a choice of which of these vectors are $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ because this will obviously have an impact when we carry out the inner product and swapping would give different answers.

Comment: Why does getting different answers matter?

Comment: You pick whichever you think will make the calculations easier. There is no "correct" choice, because there is no "correct" or unique orthonormal basis.

Comment: The Gram-Schmidt process operates on an ordered basis, so whatever order your ordered basis is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the vectors in any order you like.   You will still get an orthonormal basis from the Gram-Schmidt process (though,  in general,  a different one).